# Remove store-language-container; magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, layout-update

Magento newbie here - I have followed the Magento C.E. 1.9 RWD Designer's Guide instructions/tutorial with success with regard to where it leaves off.  I have successfully created a directory structure, copied over files from images and scss to my new theme, and verified my new theme.  I understand that the preferred method to make layout changes is through theme.xml.  I have successfully created this basic file.  I also understand that changes should be made by layout update and not through local.xml.

With all this being said, I can not seem to figure out how to create and structure a layout update to remove the language switcher/store-language-container.(though I could probably hack it but I'd like to learn the right way)  Specifically, the examples from Eric Wiese and Alan Storm make generous use of the words "default" in the examples and other words in the "<>" brackets that I can't seem to follow and apply to my directory structure (For example, I can't figure out what "" is referencing in Eric Wiese's tutorial).  I admit I'm rather new to XML.

So, can someone help me discern how to create the XML files to remove the language switcher/store-language-container using the preferred XML method?  I am hopeful that this example will help me with the rest of the modifications I need to make.  My directory structure is exactly the same as in the Magento CE 1.9 RWD tutorial.  Thanks a million in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can also disable a language through admin  go->system ->manage store->disable language

Comment: This solution worked best in my case.  I tested @Arvind Jha solution first and it worked for me.  That is, I disabled all languages but english and refreshed.  The switcher no longer appeared. I changed the page.xml(app/design/frontend/themepackage/themename/layout/page.xml) per Arunendra.  Both worked.  I then went 1 step further and found the header.phtml in .../mytheme/template/page/html/header.phtml and commented out the store-language-container div.  This also worked however it affected the css of the welcome message so I decided to live with the extra code.

Answer (score 0):

Find page.xml in app/design/frontend/themepackage/themename/layout/page.xml
and find

```
 <block type="page/switch" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="page/switch/languages.phtml"/>
```

Comment this code
If it's not work then you can remove it by this code via local.xml:

```
<reference name="header">
   <remove name="store_language"/>
</reference>
```